# Best way to stop WhatsApp recipient from seeing conversation?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

What is the best possible way to stop or limit a contact’s ability to view our conversation history? I understanding blocking the contact does nothing to stop them from viewing the conversation. Neither does clearing/deleting the conversation. I think deleting your WhatsApp account is the best way because it will render your profile blank? I want all messages from me to the person to be as disconnected from me as possible.

Comment: I don't believe this is possibls under the T&Cs.  Deleting your account will still leave the conversation visible against your phone number , if not your name.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. The conversations are stored *locally*, both on the sender *and the recipient*. There's no way to force delete lifetime conversation history on the recipient side.

Comment: You cannot erase chat history from the recipient's phone. Recipient also has it backed up.